# EmEditor v20.8 and v20.9 can't open some xml file

Tags: xml, emeditor

Both v20.8.0, v20.8.1 and v20.9.0 can't open some xml file over 0.5MB. The size is 512*1024=524288 Bytes exactly.
The character code of these files is ANSI, but there are some multibyte characters in them.
When I selected the files and right-clicked them with context menu in file explorer, the files with size under 524288 Bytes can be open normally, first choose encoding of course. But other files with size 524289 Bytes can't be open, the dialog choosing encoding flashed across.
En, v20.7.2 and before does all well.

I had sent a sample file to tech @ emurasoft.com.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't appear to be a programming problem. Bug reports for third-party software should be direction to their customer service / tech support contacts.

Comment: Please send a sample file (after zipped) to tech @ emurasoft.com with detailed descriptions of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be fixed on v20.9.1 or later.
To work around, please go to Configuration Properties of **XML**, select the **File** page, and deselect **Detect HTML/XML Charset** and/or **Detect UTF-8**. To change the XML configuration properties, select the **Tools** menu, **Select Configuration**, and **XML**.  Then select **Tools** menu, **Properties for Current Configuration**.